# Is there a way to tell which file (script, specifically) executed a command?

Tags: linux, process, monitoring

I'm running Slackware 13.37, and I was wondering if there was a way to tell which script executed a command. I tracked the process and its arguments, but I would like to know where the command originated from.

Comment: In what type of scenario: is the command running at the time of your investigation? Do you want to investigate all executions of the command or just some? Can you set up a monitoring method beforehand or is this strictly forensic? Can you control all the ways the command is run? Can you modify the command's executable? Browsing [`process`+`monitoring`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process+monitoring) might provide inspiration.

Answer (score 4):

There is no guaranteed generic way to do that apart from walking the process tree (by looking at the commands `PPID`, then that process's `PPID`, etc...).

There's a good utility for that though, if you're not trying to script something: [`pstree`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?pstree+1). It will give you a "graphical" view of the process hierarchy. Something like:

```
$ pstree -a
 ...
  ├─udevd --daemon
  │   ├─udevd --daemon
  │   └─udevd --daemon
  ├─urxvt
  │   └─bash
  │       └─pstree -ah
  └─xdm
      ├─X :0 vt7 -auth /var/lib/xdm/authdir/authfiles/A:0-g8w3zk
      └─xdm
          └─awesome
              ├─chrome
              │   ├─chrome
              │   └─21*[{chrome}]
              └─qmpdclient
                  └─{qmpdclient}
```

There are options to show the `PID`s, show or hide the command lines, etc...

Comment: You can also use `ps -axf`. The `f` is for *forrest*, but it looks like a tree. ;-)